# Не удается подключить LESS к проекту

Tags: css, less

Делаю всё по науке - качаю less.min.js отсюда [lesscss.ru](https://lesscss.ru/#download-options), кладу в папку проекта, подключаю к страничке следующим образом:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="./styles.less" type="text/less">
<script src="./less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

В styles.less у меня лежат стили в less, в less.min.js, соответственно, сам скрипт, но почему-то ничего не подключается. Браузер пишет следующую ошибку:

> Failed to load
>   file:///C:/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE/Site/public/styles.less:
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Вопрос - в чем же тут дело? less в файле валидный, проверено Winless.

Comment: а вы не рассматриваете less из пакета gulp ?

Comment: в вашем случае надо локальный сервер

Comment: Вы открываете страницу как файл (`file://...`)? Поднимите веб-сервер. Или смотрите как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local) люди заводят хром с опцией `--allow-file-access-from-files`. Когда решите проблему, разместите тут ответ. Проблема не в LESS, а в политике безопасности Хрома

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо за наводку, совершенно забыла про политику безопасности.:)

Пока решала проблему локальным сервером, выяснила, что данный способ подключения стилей к проекту вообще не является оптимальным с точки зрения лишней работы, выполняемой клиентом, и лучше использовать альтернативный - собирать всё (и стили в том числе) в бандл, и подключать уже готовый файл js.

На всякий случай, рецепт - для сборки я использовала Webpack. Для того, чтобы он прочитал стили в less, помимо Webpack, нужно установить загрузчики less-loader, сss-loader, style-loader, и настроить файл webpack.config.js следующим образом:

```
module.exports = {
entry: './app.js',
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.less$/, 

      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
    }]
}
```

};

В entry указывается файл, который надо собрать, а в output - файл, получаемый на выходе. В loader перечисляем загрузчики для обработки less и css, а в test пишем регулярку, по которой загрузчики находят, какой файл следует обработать. В файле app.js должен быть подключен файл со стилями:

```
require('./less/main.less');
```

Теперь после запуска Webpack получаем файл bundle.js, содержащий всю js-логику, стили и зависимости, который и подключаем в index.html:

```
<script src= "./dist/bundle.js" >
```

В таком виде всё работает.